# Can I parse dates in different formats?

Tags: python, pandas

A collaborator of mine has inconsistent date formatting in their data.

```
0   13/11/2016
1   21/01/2017
2   22/01/2017
3   2017-02-02
4   2016-12-11
5   13/11/2016
6   2016-12-12
7   21/01/2017
8   22/01/2017
9   2017-02-02
```

I'd like to be able to parse this into a timestamp for analysis in python.  Using `parse_dates = True` doesn't work, and I suspect it is because of the mixture of formats.

Can I parse dates in different formats?

Comment: Use try-except-ValueError and parse the row by every possible date -time format in your file.

Comment: Does your collaborator send both US and European dates? If so, how would you evaluate `01-02-2017`? Is it the 1 Feb 2017 or is it 2 Jan 2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

First format (`YYYY-MM-DD`):

```
print (df)
        dates
0  13/11/2016
1  21/01/2017
2  22/01/2017
3  2017-02-02
4  2016-12-11
5  13/11/2016
6  2016-12-12
7  21/01/2017
8  22/01/2017
9  2017-02-02
9  2017-02-25 <- YYYY-MM-DD

dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
print (dates)
0   2016-11-13
1   2017-01-21
2   2017-01-22
3   2017-02-02
4   2016-12-11
5   2016-11-13
6   2016-12-12
7   2017-01-21
8   2017-01-22
9   2017-02-02
9   2017-02-25
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Second format (`YYYY-DD-MM`)

It is a bit problematic - need parameter `format` and `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (df)
        dates
0  13/11/2016
1  21/01/2017
2  22/01/2017
3  2017-02-02
4  2016-12-11
5  13/11/2016
6  2016-12-12
7  21/01/2017
8  22/01/2017
9  2017-02-02
9  2017-25-02 <- YYYY-DD-MM

dates1 = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce')
dates2 = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format='%Y-%d-%m', errors='coerce')

dates = dates1.combine_first(dates2)
#dates = dates1.fillna(dates2)
print (dates)
0   2016-11-13
1   2017-01-21
2   2017-01-22
3   2017-02-02
4   2016-11-12
5   2016-11-13
6   2016-12-12
7   2017-01-21
8   2017-01-22
9   2017-02-02
9   2017-02-25
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```