# python pandas parse_dates for multiple columns in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working on Python pandas for two csv files comparison but in csv files having 5 date columns i've used parse_date=['dateofbirth','lastupdates','dateofjoin','dateofresign,'endoftrade'] in read_csv method but it is only parsing dateofbirth not all the columns in csv file.

code:

```
csv_pandas=pd.read_csv("path of the csv file",parse_date=['dateofbirth','lastupdates','dateofjoin','dateofresign,'endoftrade'])
print(csv_pandas)
```

CSV File:

```
dateofbirth             lastupdates       dateofjoin          dateofresign 
05/06/2021 00:00:00PM 12/13/2021 12:00:00PM 12/13/2021 12:00:00PM 12/13/2021 12:00:00PM

column        non-null count   Dtype
------        -------------    ------
dateofbirth    non-null         object
dateofbirth    non-null         datetime64[ns]
dateofbirth    non-null         datetime64[ns]
dateofbirth    non-null         datetime64[ns]
```

I can able to convert only object Dtype column,remaining datetime64[ns] not parsing

Around i've 160 csv files ,each csv file have different column names ,Can any one plz suggest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I parse dates in different formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546367/can-i-parse-dates-in-different-formats)

Comment: The problem is because it's missing a whitespace between `00PM`. You have to modify your input files or create a custom parser and set `date_parser` parameter.

Comment: @Alex. I think the answer does not fit the case of OP.

Comment: @Corralien, maybe. I cannot reproduce their issue though. The only column that doesn't parse for me is `dateofbirth`. I think the issue is the milliseconds field.

Comment: Alex in my code need to parse two csv files source and target then i need to compare but it is not working for all columns

Comment: @Alex is right. The problem is the milliseconds field. `dateofbirth` is not a `datetime64` valid column.

Comment: I've edited my question and incase in csv file has single date column then able to parse successfully but more than 1 date column not able to parse in csv file

Comment: Update your post with the output of `csv_pandas.info()`, please

Comment: @Corralien Updated with csv_pandas.info() ,and i can only convert dateofbirth but remaining not converting

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can able to convert only object Dtype column,remaining datetime64[ns] not parsing'? What is your goal?

Comment: After parse_date=['dateofbirth','lastupdates','dateofjoin','dateofresign'] ,when i open csv file only dateofbirth column values are parsed and remaining column values are not parsed,shows as it is.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible for us. Everything seems working. I don't understand where is the problem with your data and code :-(

Answer (score 1):

- you have two date formats that require different `strptime()` format instructions.
- not all of the columns you are trying to convert exist in data frame, so testing that column exists in **dict** comprehension that is pass as ****kwargs** to `assign()`

```
csv_pandas = csv_pandas.assign(
    **{
        c: pd.to_datetime(csv_pandas[c], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f", errors="ignore")
        for c in parse_date
        if c in csv_pandas.select_dtypes("object").columns
    }
).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(
        **{
            c: pd.to_datetime(d[c], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", errors="ignore")
            for c in parse_date
            if c in d.select_dtypes("object").columns
        }
    )
)
```

#### output

```
csv_pandas.dtypes
dateofbirth     datetime64[ns]
lastupdates     datetime64[ns]
dateofjoin      datetime64[ns]
dateofresign    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```